# Is there a metallicity threshold past which star formation is impossible?

Tags: star, star-formation, metallicity

I've learned that metallicity is a very important factor to consider when talking about a star's formation and lifecycle. That gets me wondering whether a high enough metallicity could prevent the formation of proper stars altogether. Would it happen when the metallicity is so high that the hydrogen concentration isn't high enough to initiate a self-sustaining fusion reaction?

Comment: There is no limit associated with phenomenon you suggest, it just raises the minimum mass for "starhood".

Comment: Couldn't it hypothetically be so high that the mass required to initiate fusion would cause the would-be star to simply collapse into a black hole? Not that I'm saying this could ever happen.

Comment: No. It would rise to around half a solar mass if there were no hydrogen at all at which point the helium would burn. Or about 1 solar mass and the carbon and oxygen would burn.

Comment: Sounds like the only way to keep fusion from happening at all would be if a would-be star's chemical makeup was devoid of any elements capable of exothermic fusion reactions.

Comment: Maybe you'd be interested in the so called "quasi-star" (or black hole star) which is powered by a compact object at their cores https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-star

Comment: @DaddyKropotkin I thought high metallicity would keep a quasi-star from forming.

Comment: Some Stars are Totally Metal: A New Mechanism Driving Dust Across Star-Forming Clouds, and Consequences for Planets, Stars, and Galaxies http://arxiv.org/abs/1406.5509